# Does anyone know who created or where this He-Man and Battlecat image came from?

Tags: art, he-man

Saw this years ago, and heard tell this was some imagery around a proposed *He-Man & the Masters of the Universe* update movie. Nothing seems to have come of that, though.

Still, the image is wonderful, and I was wondering if there were any more done of the characters in this style?

Or perhaps (since it seems to be fan art) if someone knew who created it?

[image: Man and Bat]

Comment: Searching for the art on Tineye suggests it's a deviantart creation. Alas I cannot follow the link while mobile

Comment: @Valorum As far as I can tell it does appear to be a Deviant Art creation, yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This appears to be by the Deviant Art user [nebezial](https://www.deviantart.com/nebezial). Whilst I can't be sure, it was published 14/03/2009 which is roughly when the new film was first rumoured to be in production as far as I can tell. The original post is [here](https://www.deviantart.com/nebezial/art/he-man-teaser-style-115891770).

The artist also has a lot of other similar art, with [this one](https://www.deviantart.com/nebezial/art/he-man-and-the-masters-of-the-universe-cover-490688129) perhaps being the closest.

[image: He-Man art by nebezial]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you. That does seem to answer the question.

Comment: It appears to have had a number of unattributed usages; I found one on [Gizmodo](https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-he-man-movie-just-got-a-new-writer-and-heres-why-i-1725339408) for example, several on YouTube and other places too.

Comment: @DavidW Oh it's been used all over the place. I had to filter out wallpaper websites, for example.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Sure, that's why I checked Gizmodo; I figured even a CC BY-SA image should be properly attributed on a commercial site... :-P